# OpenAPI Swagger codegen Spring Boot: Validation of an enum as a path variable

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger 2.0

My endpoint

```
  /api/ideas/{idea_id}/{field}:
put:
  tags:
    - ideas
  operationId: UpdateIdeaField
  description: Update a field in an idea
  parameters:
    - name: idea_id
      in: path
      type: integer
      required: true
    - name: field
      in: path
      required: true
      type: string
      enum: [division,executive_sponsor,platform_contact]
```

I would like it so that when I use an invalid enum, it throws 400. However right now with a non valid enum, it accepts it.

What swagger codegen is generating

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "updateIdeaField", notes = "Update a field in an idea", response = IdeaVM.class, authorizations = {
    @Authorization(value = "openId", scopes = {
        
        })
}, tags={ "ideas", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Idea updated", response = IdeaVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = ProblemVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ProblemVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = ProblemVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = ProblemVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity", response = ProblemVM.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Something went wrong", response = ProblemVM.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/ideas/{idea_id}/{field}",
    produces = { "application/json", "application/problem+json" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.PUT)
default ResponseEntity<IdeaVM> _updateIdeaField(@ApiParam(value = "",required=true) @PathVariable("idea_id") Integer ideaId,@ApiParam(value = "",required=true, allowableValues = "\"division\", \"executive_sponsor\", \"platform_contact\"") @PathVariable("field") String field) {
    return updateIdeaField(ideaId, field);
}

// Override this method
default ResponseEntity<IdeaVM> updateIdeaField(Integer ideaId,String field) {
    if(getObjectMapper().isPresent() && getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
        if (getAcceptHeader().get().contains("application/json")) {
            try {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(getObjectMapper().get().readValue("{  \"submitted_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"gp_status\" : \"IN_REVIEW\",  \"challenge_id\" : 897,  \"account_executive\" : \"0f4c0f7e-18ce-4b7c-bd48-f4121790dd90\",  \"platform_contact\" : \"Walter Waldo\",  \"public_id\" : \"201e6466-6924-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003\",  \"entered_gate_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"division\" : \"Asett Managment\",  \"idea_type\" : \"201e6466-6924-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003\",  \"read_only\" : false,  \"collaborators\" : [ \"b4bd2cc9-def8-4b85-86d3-40fb0225542a\", \"400f3605-864a-4cb1-8968-03c831fc49e8\" ],  \"publication_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"rank\" : 1576844,  \"id\" : 1,  \"views_count\" : 201,  \"pending_collaborators\" : [ \"john.smith1@companydomain.com\", \"john.smith2@companydomain.com\" ],  \"brief\" : \"We want to explore and ideate solutions which can be utilised to increase last minute bookings\",  \"owner\" : \"0f4c0f7e-18ce-4b7c-bd48-f4121790dd90\",  \"image_link\" : \"https\",  \"idea_description\" : {    \"answers\" : [ {      \"answer\" : \"The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is... 42\",      \"question_id\" : 1    }, {      \"answer\" : \"The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is... 42\",      \"question_id\" : 1    } ]  },  \"creation_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"modified_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"killed_on_hold_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"executive_sponsor\" : \"Wally Waldo\",  \"tags\" : [ \"Cancellation\", \"Last minute bookins\", \"Delays\", \"Satisfaction\" ],  \"total_invested\" : 132000,  \"likes_count\" : 126,  \"review_date\" : \"2019-10-03T22:45:465Z\",  \"mentors\" : [ \"b4bd2cc9-def8-4b85-86d3-40fb0225542a\", \"400f3605-864a-4cb1-8968-03c831fc49e8\" ],  \"followers_count\" : 7,  \"name\" : \"Last minute booking promotions\",  \"is_public\" : false,  \"gate\" : {    \"active\" : true,    \"id\" : 1,    \"display_name\" : \"Discovery\",    \"key\" : \"gate_discovery\",    \"order\" : 1  },  \"status\" : \"DRAFT\"}", IdeaVM.class), HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Couldn't serialize response for content type application/json", e);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default IdeasApi interface so no example is generated");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

I appreciate any help

Olehs suggestion is the following,The output generated is still the same. The field is a String in the generated interface and I can send non valid enums

```
  /api/ideas/{idea_id}/{field}:
put:
  tags:
    - ideas
  operationId: UpdateIdeaField
  description: Update a field in an idea
  parameters:
    - name: idea_id
      in: path
      type: integer
      required: true
    - name: field
      in: path
      required: true
      type: string
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MyEnum'
    - in: body
      name: value
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateIdeaFieldRequest'
```

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to create a separate enum object?

```
MyEnum:
  type: string
  enum:
 - value1
 - value2
```

```
/api/ideas/{idea_id}/{field}:
put:
  tags:
    - ideas
  operationId: UpdateIdeaField
  description: Update a field in an idea
  parameters:
    - name: idea_id
      in: path
      type: integer
      required: true
    - name: field
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MyEnum'
    - in: body
      name: value
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateIdeaFieldRequest'
```

and then just use `$ref` to that enum

Comment: So i tried the following and it is still mapped as a String in the generated code, and still the same. I can send an invalid enum

Comment: in you example you still user schema + type. use only schema

Comment: If I remove schema, it fails generation.

Comment: you didn't get) leave schema but remote type in the parameter declaration

```
- name: field
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/MyEnum'
```

Comment: sorry could you please edit your OP for the correct formatting

Comment: For anyone who finds this, schema validation warns about parameters with a reference schema unless it's specified as being in the body of the request. The specific schema warning is `Schema validation: Value should be one of: "body"`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try creating a custom converter to convert String to an Enum as shown here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param#clone

Comment: Please don't rely on an external link for the "how" part of your answer. Answers should be self-contained and only link to other sites for reference. If that site were to disappear or move in the future, this answer should still be useful for others.